# Python: How to call the values in a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a newbie of Python. In the following code(or see attached), I want to call all the numbers input inside a string in the last step of the program. How should I do that?

```
print "how old are you?",
age = raw_input()
print "how tall are you?",
height = raw_input()

print = (expected outcome: You're X old, X tall, etc.)
```

Comment: https://pyformat.info/#simple

Comment: Python has a [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.format) function that allows you to format strings using variables.

Comment: `print("expected outcome: You're " + str(age) + " old, " + str(height) + " tall, etc.")` for python3 or `print "expected outcome: You're " + str(age) + " old, " + str(height) + " tall, etc."` for python2

Answer (score 1):

one simple way that i prefer is to use the string formatting operator like this:

```
>>> age = 10
>>> height = 72
>>> print "you're %s years old and %s cm tall" % (age, height)
you're 10 years old and 72 cm tall
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can print as many thing as you want for example:

```
print "You're", age, "years old and", height, "centimeters tall"
```

or you can use string format

```
print "You're {} years old and {} centimeters tall".format(age,height)
```

example

```
>>> age=29
>>> height=160
>>> print "You're", age, "years old and", height, "centimeters tall"
You're 29 years old and 160 centimeters tall
>>> print "You're {} years old and {} centimeters tall".format(age,height)
You're 29 years old and 160 centimeters tall
>>>
```

there are several ways on how to do it as illustrated in the others answers and comments, my favorite is the [string format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Also if you need to convert those input in numbers to do math on them use `int` or `float` accordingly

```
x = int(raw_input("write a number: "))
```

furthermore, as you are learning python I recommend starting with the newest version, python 3.5 you can later ajust to older version if needed

Answer (score 0):

Cool!, welcome to coding in python!, there are lots of ways to do what you want, i'll show you one, but feel free to look for another

```
print "how old are you?",
age = raw_input()
print "how tall are you?",
height = raw_input()

print("You're " + age + " old, " + height + " tall, etc.")
```

EXTRA: you can add params to `raw_input` and make it like:

```
age = raw_input("how old are you?")
height = raw_input("how tall are you?")

print("You're " + age + " old, " + height + " tall, etc.")
```

Comment: Thanks! What adjustment can I make in the last line "print ---" in order to make a number that is called followed by a comma?

Comment: sorry did not understand the question, what do you want as output?

Comment: print "how old are you?",
age = raw_input()
print "how tall are you?",
height = raw_input()
print "how much do you want?",
cash = raw_input()

print("You're " + age + " old, " + height + " tall," + " want " + cash)

I would like the output to be: You're 22 old, 160 tall, want 99999.
I am not sure how to put a full stop after the input '99999'.

Comment: maybe by `full stop` you meant `dont put a new line at the end`, that you can do (i'm assuming you are ussing python2.7 its the same on python3 but there is also a easy way in python3). you can `import sys; sys.stdout.write("You're " + age + " old, " + height + " tall," + " want " + cash)` (NOTE: if this is what you want, you can import sys only once). let me know if this what you meant